# Retrieving data from the table using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to know all the Select Statement that is used to retrieve the data of one particular table  from  the database.
I have used .First and .FirstOrDefault it gives me the desired result but when i use .Last it throws me an error.My feeling is that .First gives us the first row of the table so why error in .Last and why we use .FirstOrDefault because .First will surely give us First row so why to use .FirstOrDefault and what is the default value of it as it is used to be away from the any exception and please let me know the other  functions as well to retrieve the data from the table.
I have used

```
var val=db.AccountBank .First();//gives me the Result
var val1=db.AccountBank .Last();//gives me the following error
```

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Invoice.AccountBank LastAccountBank' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use orderby decending and Take(1) because Linq can not translate the Last() to any valid sql statment.

```
AccountBank.OrderByDescending().Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: but why??I can even do it by AccountBank.ToList().Last(); as well

Comment: and i need others function as well

Comment: When you use `ToList().Last()` the records are fetched from the database and then the last one is selected. If you do First or FirstOrDefault the query will use TOP 1 to retreive the record.

Comment: yes but to retreive it fetched from the database only right??so why not in case of .Last() in my feeling it .First() it must fetch the First row and in .Last() it must fetch Last row from the table

Comment: Unfortunately LINQ to SQL doesn't work that way. As Nilesh said, using `.ToList().Last` "caches" the data into a list, then chooses the last one from that. This may or may not solve your problem, especially if you are using a large set of data. You will just need to think out what functions you need and find out if LINQ is capable of doing them. If not, you'll just have to hack something together.